# How to pass objects around middleware(s) and handler in go echo?

Tags: go, server, go-echo

I am using [echo](https://github.com/labstack/echo) to build a web server in go. What is the best way to pass objects around middlewares and a handler apart from using context.Set method?

For example, let's consider the following case:

```
func mw(next echo.HandlerFunc) echo.HandlerFunc {
  return func(c echo.Conext) error {
    var value TypeX = // load value of type TypeX based on query parameters
    c.Set("key", value)
    return next(c)
  }
}

func h1(c echo.context) error {
  value := c.Get("key").(TypeX)
  return c.JSON(http.StatusOk, value.H1())
}

func h2(c echo.context) error {
  value := c.Get("key").(TypeX)
  return c.JSON(http.StatusOk, value.H2())
}

func registerRoute(e *echo.Echo) {
  e.Get("/test", h)
}
```

Is there any way to get rid of get/set methods? It seems like an unclean way of doing this operation. I am open to complete refactoring, creating new structures/interfaces to make this happen.

To take this example further, lets say my apis can fall into bucket1, bucket2, bucket3. `Value` would call the method `b1`, `b2`, `b3` based on which bucked it falls in. These buckets can be identified by adding them as middleware `mwB1`, `mwB2`, `mwB3` each of which calls the respective method. Hence, all my apis would first call the middleware `mw`; then one of `mwB1`, `mwB2`, `mwB3` and finally the actual handler, something like, `e.Get("/test", h, mw, mwB2)`. I don't want to load `value` everywhere and get/set seems unclean to me (unless that is the standard way of doing this).

Comment: What use cases of this passed value? Why should you use middleware to create this value?

Comment: Lets say my apis can fall into bucket1, bucket2, bucket3. Value would call the method b1, b2, b3 based on which bucked it falls in. These buckets can be identified by adding them as middleware mwB1, mwB2, mwB3 each of which calls the respective method

Comment: @OlegButuzov I have updated the question to clear it out further.

Comment: It's easier to pass something to context than substitute response writer and change response in middleware. so yeah, you can do it in this way.

Comment: @kernel0707 If I understand clearly it does not seem usable, I don't understand why would you need multiple middlewares with Context to set and get query parameters which can be accessed directly in handlers